# WooCommerce пропадает html в значениях атрибутов товара при импорте

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, csv, импорт

Использую для импорта встроенный в WooCommerce 3.8.0 плагин для импорта. (Товары -> Импорт).

Проблема в следующем: Я импортирую товар, вот его атрибут (Разъемы):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в итоге оно вставляет его в следующем виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если я проделаю тоже самое руками (вставлю html код в значение атрибута и сохраню товар), то все отлично:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Что я могу сделать, чтобы при импорте сохранялась HTML-разметка значения атрибута?

P.S. Заметил что HTML-разметка в "Описание товара" сохраняется отлично при импорте, а вот в значениях атрибутов почему-то нет.

P.S.S. Также прикрепляю файлы модуля, который отвечает за импорт.
https://github.com/khmelev77/wordpress-csv-importer

Пример csv для импорта:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDzDD4th4_1yYyM6YqNx4I0K3EITGhQR_6qVljWY4Pw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Можете скинуть пример файла для импорта?

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавил ссылку

Comment: я имел ввиду сам пример файла csv :)

Answer (score 0):

Надо чтобы каждое свойство было разделено или запятой или |  в зависимости от инструмента. Сейчас получается добавление индивидуального свойства товара. Чтобы атрибут был глобальным, надо в файле это указать 1 - это да, 0 - это нет. И все должно быть по столбцам.  Вот примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]